# How is possible to play an alarm in iOS if the application is closed?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, notifications

I downloaded some Alarm Clock apps from the App Store and found they are able to keep playing a sound and even vibrating the phone for more than 30 seconds (Limitations from UILocalNotifications) I even forced to close the application and it still work!

I wonder how is this possible? Is there another method than UILocalNotification ? 
Are they using several notifications?

Thanks!

Comment: Push notifications? I really am not sure... Just an idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They could be using Push Notifications, but that would require an external server, internet, and is unlikely.

What is more likely is that they are just using UILocalNotifications.  When you schedule one to go off at a specific time, it will go off at that time even if the app has been quit.  The OS will direct all Local Notifications once they have been scheduled.  Here's the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on UILocalNotification.

EDIT: In response to your comment, scheduling one Local Notification, followed by scheduling a second one for 30 seconds later, and so on, is plausible.  And to me, it seems like the only way if there is a 30 second restriction.

Comment: Im sure they are using UILocalNotification, but local notification only allow you to play a sound for 30''. This is making me think that they are using 10 or 15 UILocalNotifications and when you open the app they dismissed them.

Comment: That could be possible. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that if you schedule a UILocalNotification, the OS takes control of the notification and will execute it even when the application that scheduled it closes.

Comment: I miss the obvious on a daily basis :)

Answer (score 1):

They could be background-capable audio apps (using UIBackgroundModes in the app's plist) and playing silence, using Audio Queues or the RemoteIO Audio Unit, even in the background,  until time to mix in some alarm sounds or music.

Comment: The problem is App Store doesn't allow you to use background-capable apps to make alarm clocks...